# when to use `mongoose.disconnect()` or `db.close()`

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB. Now I am using Mongoose to take care of the database in my express.js app. My question is that I don't know when should I close the connection? Since someone says better to close it, while someone else says to leave it open? And what is the difference between `db.close()` and `mongoose.disconnect()`? What is your experience of using these?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless your server has a shutdown routine, I think you can just leave it open. You're gonna need a db connection to handle your requests. Otherwise, you need to re-open it for every request.

Comment: so only close it when the process exits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open a connection and share that between your routes/services. You can initialize the db and all related schema before you start express.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

// define models
import User from './user';
import Order from './order';

// connect to db
const connect = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

  return mongoose.connection;
};

const models = { User, Order };

export { connect };

export default models;
```

Then connect before you startup Express:

```
import models, { connect } from './models';
...

// connect to the db
const connection = await connect();

// now pass in the models to your routes
request('./routes/users')(models);
request('./routes/orders')(models);

// or use middleware so you can access in routes like req.models.user.find({})
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.models = models;
  next();
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
   console.log(`Example app listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`),
);
```

You can add a cleanup handler to listen to process.exit and close the connection there. Roughly something like:

```
const cleanUp = (eventType) => {
  connection.close(() => {
       console.info('closed');
   });
};

[`exit`, `SIGINT`, `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2`, `uncaughtException`, `SIGTERM`].forEach((eventType) => {
  process.on(eventType, cleanUp.bind(null, eventType));
})
```

Comment: Thank you! So that means I should connect to the db before the server is run, and then when process.exit, then close the connection? So what you mean is that I should only open it one time and leave it on until the process is done?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you said